# Integrating web-based application with QuickBooks Online

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have a web-based application, which integrates with QuickBooks through the QuickBooks Web Connector. This works great for desktop versions of QuickBooks. However, I'm looking to add support for QuickBooks Online, and the Web Connector can't be used with QuickBooks Online.

How do I integrate my application with QuickBooks Online? If possible, I'd like to use the web service that is already working with the Web Connector.

Comment: Is this a one-off/internal integration (e.g. you're using it with ONE QuickBooks file) or is this a SaaS app (e.g. you're allowing your customers to connect their QuickBooks files to your app)? Your answer to this will influence the direction you should go.

Comment: @KeithPalmer This is a SaaS app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit http://developer.intuit.com and click on the Integrate your app with QuickBooks link in the Intuit Partner Platform section.  The link brings up our QuickBooks API documentation.  You should focus on the V2 API if you want something that will be ready to use now.  The V3 API will be released publically later this year and will allow you to integrate your application with the Global version of QuickBooks Online.

Register as a developer and if you have any further questions you can submit a support ticket and we'll get back to you.

Comment: Be aware that this if you're building a one-off/internal integration (vs. a SaaS app) then this is NOT the correct direction to go.

Comment: This is a good start, thank you. It looks like by using V2 API and adding a "Connect to QuickBooks" button within my app, I can allow users to trigger a sync similar to what I currently do with the Web Connector. Do I understand correctly that my app has to be published in order to implement any sort of integration with QuickBooks Online? And, before publishing, I must submit my app for a security review?

Comment: You definitely have to go through security review with Intuit. You don't have to be listed on AppCenter.Intuit.com if you don't want to.